# Section accordion for attributes in design resource for custom lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, design-attributes

In building custom lighting components with lots of admin-configurable properties, our design resource interface can get quite lengthy.

It would be nice if we could have collapsible sections in the design resource to allow admins to open/close groups of attributes at a time.

I saw this in a demo at TrailheadDX (image below) but haven't found anything in the docs for how to do this.  Does anyone know how to implement this?[image]

Comment: I dont believe we have any power into styling or adding custom markup in the design fiel popup of our componetnts unfortunately